# Applescript Automatic copy a file when mount usbkey

Tags: copy, applescript, usb-drive

Hi I'm trying to automatic copy a file when I insert a USBkey on my mac.
It's possible also automatic unmount the volume when the copy is finished?

Thanks

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    repeat with aItem in these_items
        tell application "Finder"
            if (local volume of aItem) and (name of aItem is "[Name of Hard Drive]") then
                display dialog "USBKEYY"
                duplicate file "7605_NOK.jpg" of folder desktopPath to local volume of aItem


            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 1):

In the repeat loop try this after the duplicate statement. I believe it will automatically wait until the file is copied before trying to eject the disk.

```
eject disk "[Name of USB disk]"
exit repeat
```